# Merging tables and getting the output in ascending order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as such:

```
student                                   department
id  department_id                      department_id  department_name

5     5                                  5              Computer Science
1     4                                  4              Architecture
3     2                                  1              Mathematics
4     5                                  3              Chemistry
2     4                                  2              Physics
```

I wrote a query as follow and got the following results.

```
SELECT DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_NAME AS D, STUDENTS.DEPT_ID AS D_ID
FROM STUDENTS 
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS
ON STUDENTS.DEPT_ID=DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_ID ;



Computer Science 5
Computer Science 5
Physics 2
Architecture 4
Architecture 4
```

It's fine till here but I want something like

```
Computer Science 2
Architecture 2
Physics 1
Chemistry 0
Mathematics 0
```

i.e department name , num_of students where num_of students are in decending order.

What can I add to the query?

Answer (score 2):

I would use COUNT(*) and subquery it for the ORDER BY

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_NAME, COUNT(*) AS num_ofstudents
FROM STUDENTS 
LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENTS
ON STUDENTS.DEPT_ID=DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY Departments.Dept_name
) AS a ORDER BY num_ofstudents
```

edit- Thanks AaronDietz for pointing this out!
You should replace the `INNER JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN` so that the query includes the records from [Departments] that do not have any students. Also, I did not need to include the subquery.

```
SELECT DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_NAME, COUNT(*) AS num_ofstudents
FROM STUDENTS 
LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENTS
ON STUDENTS.DEPT_ID=DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY Departments.Dept_name
ORDER BY num_ofstudents
```

Comment: Why do you need a derived table and a `LEFT` join?

Comment: @AaronDietz- You're right about not needing a derived table. Learner needs to left join so that the output includes the departments with 0 students.

Comment: Always helps OP to explain that and the other answers mostly missed the left join. ;)  Anyway, nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try grouping the departments and the id, then count.

```
SELECT DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_NAME AS D, COUNT(*) as NID
FROM STUDENTS 
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS
ON STUDENTS.DEPT_ID=DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_ID 
GROUP BY DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_NAME
ORDER BY NID DESC
```

Comment: You've beaten me by two minutes ,-) But why the double group by?

Comment: @Lothar Wow, should double check my code next time, yeah btw nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest approach is to select the departments and get the count in a subquery:

```
select
  department_id,
  department_name,
  (select count(*) from student s where s.department_id = d.department_id) as student_count
from department d
order by 3 desc;
```

This works well, because you just want one value from the students, namely the count. If you wanted more information then you'd move the subquery to the from clause. E.g.:

```
select
  d.department_id,
  d.department_name,
  colalesce(s.students, 0) as student_count,
  s.ids as student_ids
from department d
left join
(
  select 
    department_id,
    count(*) as students,
    group_concat(id) as ids
  from student
  group by department_id
) s on s.department_id = d.department_id
order by 3 desc;
```

Comment: awesome..thanks.. I was also working on making the Architecture show up first than computer science ( arrange alphabetically if they have equal rank by count in third column) .. any hint on that? like how to modify the order by statement?  I am just starting to learn sql

Comment: Yes, that's simple. Just add to order by, e.g. `order by 3 desc, 2`, or with names `order by student_count desc, department_name` which may be a tad more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_NAME AS D, count(STUDENTS.DEPT_ID) AS D_ID
FROM STUDENTS 
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS
ON STUDENTS.DEPT_ID=DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY D
ORDER BY D_ID DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by department name 
Other queries are mostly right but `COUNT` should be on student id and query should start from `department` instead of `student`.

```
SELECT DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_NAME, 
       COUNT(id) AS num_ofstudents
FROM DEPARTMENT 
LEFT JOIN students ON STUDENTS.DEPT_ID = DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY DEPARTMENTS.DEPT_NAME
ORDER BY num_ofstudents
```